# Connecting to the Tor network with Python without getting "Proxy server is refusing connection"

Tags: python, tor

I've been trying to use Tor via Python only to come across the "Proxy server is refusing connection" error.

I've trying this method using the Stem library:
http://www.thedurkweb.com/automated-anonymous-interactions-with-websites-using-python-and-tor/

Any help to fixing this error?

Here is the code:

```
import stem.process
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
from splinter import Browser

proxyIP = "127.0.0.1"
proxyPort = 9150

proxy_settings = {"network.proxy.type":1,
    "network.proxy.ssl": proxyIP,
    "network.proxy.ssl_port": proxyPort,
    "network.proxy.socks": proxyIP,
    "network.proxy.socks_port": proxyPort,
    "network.proxy.socks_remote_dns": True,
    "network.proxy.ftp": proxyIP,
    "network.proxy.ftp_port": proxyPort
}
browser = Browser('firefox', profile_preferences=proxy_settings)

def interactWithSite(browser):
    browser.visit("http://dogdogfish.com/python-2/generating-b2b-sales-data-in-python/")
    browser.fill("comment", "But the thing is... Why would anyone ever want to do this? I must have thought that times...")
    browser.fill("author", "Pebblor El Munchy")
    browser.fill("email", "barack@tehwhitehouz.gov")
    browser.fill("url", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/16/Drevil_million_dollars.jpg")
    button = browser.find_by_name("submit")
    button.click()

interactWithSite(browser)
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your Tor port is 9150 and not 9050?  I'd also leave ssl and ftp proxy/port settings empty since Tor is not any of those.

Comment: I deleted the SSL and FTP proxy and port settings and it worked. I also used port 9150. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted the SSL and FTP proxy and port settings and it worked. I also used port 9150.

Here is the working code:

```
import stem.process
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
from splinter import Browser

proxyIP = "127.0.0.1"
proxyPort = 9150

proxy_settings = {"network.proxy.type":1,
    "network.proxy.socks": proxyIP,
    "network.proxy.socks_port": proxyPort,
    "network.proxy.socks_remote_dns": True,
}
browser = Browser('firefox', profile_preferences=proxy_settings)

def interactWithSite(browser):
    browser.visit("http://dogdogfish.com/python-2/generating-b2b-sales-data-in-python/")
    browser.fill("comment", "But the thing is... Why would anyone ever want to do this? I must have thought that times...")
    browser.fill("author", "Pebblor El Munchy")
    browser.fill("email", "barack@tehwhitehouz.gov")
    browser.fill("url", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/16/Drevil_million_dollars.jpg")
    button = browser.find_by_name("submit")
    button.click()

interactWithSite(browser)
```